# Full width submenu with aligned submenu items

Tags: css, navigation

I'm having a problem trying to achieve a navigation design I made. 
Please see this link to have a look at the example http://lab.518studio.com/submenu

So as you will see I'm trying to have a full width submenu background, I used the `position:absolute;` but it presents me two new problems:

1. I cant get the sub-items aligned with the main item.
2. Content below it will not move down when it displays.

Basically what I want to do is to get the position of parent items under the correspondent main item and have the content below it moving when submenu is displayed.

I placed a link on the URL to download the HTML and CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Make the menu `li` `position:relative` and give submenu `ul` a width